# paramiko upload folder via sftp

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko

Inside my working code, i have this

```
import paramiko
parent=os.path.split(dir_local)[1]
for walker in os.walk(parent):
    try:
        self.sftp.mkdir(os.path.join(dir_remote,walker))
    except:
        pass
for file in walker[2]:
    sftp.put(os.path.join(walker[0],file),os.path.join(dir_remote,walker[0],file))
```

the error now showing is

```
Trying ssh-agent key 5e08bb83615bcc303ca84abe561ef0a6 ... success
Caught exception: <type 'exceptions.IOError'>: [Errno 2] Directory does not exist.
```

The print `walker` showing all the files inside that folder but i dont know why the folder doesn't copy to sftp server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

unless you've overridden `os.walk()` it yields a tuple of three objects: `dirpath, dirnames, filenames`

So, you're `os.path.join(dir_remote, walker)` call will always throw an exception, resulting in your expected directory not being created.

I find it's clearer to write the `os.walk()` loop like this:

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(parent):
    remote_path = os.path.join(dir_remote, dirpath)
    # make remote directory ...
    for filename in filenames:
        local_path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        remote_fliepath = os.paht.join(remote_path, filename)
        # put file
```

Keep in mind that `os.walk()` will *walk* any directories in your given `parent`.

Comment: what can i use instead of os.walk() ...?

Comment: you can use walk, you just need to use it correctly.

Comment: If your only concerned about a single directory, and it's immediate children, use `os.listdir()` instead.

Comment: ok i tried >os.listdir() .. Its gives me [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '2/1'

Comment: `local_filepaths = [ os.path.join(parent, filename) for filename in os.listdir(parent)]`

Comment: shall i give like this sftp.put(local_filepaths,remote_filepath)

Comment: no, local_filepaths is a list of filepaths, you'll probably need to `.put()` each one separately.

Comment: small typo path not paht :)